# Spring change cglib

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, cglib

I am use Spring in my app, when we have some class that doesn't implements any interface, Spring will use "cglib" to proxy.

Can I change the cglib to other lib in Spring? If yes, How can I do it?

Thanks!

[EDIT]
Hi, I was wanting because I have problems with PermGen when I use CGLIB, the proxys instance are not cleaning when I do hotdeploy. 
Yes, I can change for other stretegy, Aspect etc...

Comment: Your question is unspecific. Which library do you want to use? Or do you just want to upgrade the CGLIB version? Are you willing to consider a switch to AspectJ which does not even need proxies and should also solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @kriegaex, how can I do to change to AspectJ and not generate CGLIB proxys? I don't know do it. thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be doing hot(re/de)ploys anyway as that is trouble waiting to happen. Even if you wouldn't use cglib.

Comment: @javaTry: You can either use your favourite web search engine or just follow [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring only supports *JDK (interface only)* and *CGLIB based* (for classes) proxying, and while it's not explicitly mentioned, it also uses *Objenesis* with CGLIB for proxying classes with *no default constructor*. Also see their issues regarding this at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8190 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5654 for further reference. That means there's **no drop-in replacement or configuration options** in Spring to switch to some other proxy creation method.

If you're still willing to explore uncharted territories, the `DefaultAopProxyFactory` might be a good place to start as it seems it's a central piece of the proxy creation code in Spring, the proxy creator classes use it as a factory through their common superclass `ProxyCreatorSupport`.

Comment: Hi @Nándor Előd Fekete, I was trying change cglib, because I found a problem with memory leak in class that are manipulate from cglib, the class are not clear when I do hot deploy, this cause PermGean Outofmemory, I will read today this links that you pass me.